# Oracle SQL Developer Question-xlsx export with SQL Code on 2nd Sheet Question

Tags: excel, oracle, export, double, quotes

First time posting, and I have researched this, but cannot find a clear answer.

When I export a report to xlsx in Oracle SQL Developer, it puts the SQL code on a 2nd sheet, which is great.  However, when I copy and paste that code from excel to notepad or back into oracle, it puts double quotes, ", at the beginning and end of the code, and it also puts double quotes with any existing alias double quotes.

Ex:  e.employee_name ""Employee Name""

I have tried going into Tools>Preferences>Database>Utilities>Export, but I cannot seem to find any setting there that would fix the extra double quotes.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which SQL Developer version is it? I can't see that behavior in 21.4

Comment: I currently have 19c

Comment: "19c" sounds like a **database** version, not SQL Developer version.

Comment: Sorry, it is the same Version 21.4.  Pref set up?

Comment: My setup is default, I didn't change anything.

Comment: Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: No, sorry, I wouldn't know why you got that nor how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for checking.  Keeping fingers crossed, someone may know the fix, or if it is a pref set.

Comment: No problem; I guess @thatjeffsmith might know it.